# Is the "where" keyword lazy?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

Assuming I have a function like

```
foo = 8 + f1
  where f1 = 8 + 9
        f2 = 8 + 10
```

`f1` clearly has to be evaluated, but `f2` doesn't have to be. Will it be though? I can see how evaluating every `where` expression would be a performance issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's lazy, so that `f2` will not be evaluated, for example:

```
foo = 8 + f1
    where f1 = 8 + 9
          f2 = last [1..]
```

will be calculated instantly, and would take forever if it was strict.

Comment: It's also worth noting that, interestingly, it explicitly defines how to construct a thunk, so you can change some functions' behaviours with it, such as `foldl'`.

Comment: @AJFarmar that sounds interesting, could you open up or drop a link with more details?

Comment: This may be useful: https://wiki.haskell.org/Let_vs._Where . You may have to do some wider reading, however. Also, here's the source of `foldl'`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/Data-Foldable.html#foldl%27